# Execute Powershell Command Clear-Disk via vb.NET PSCommand

Tags: .net, vb.net, powershell

I try to execute a Powershellcommand (clear-disk) via vb.NET, but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
    Dim command As New PSCommand()
    command.AddScript("clear-disk -number 1 -removedata -removeOEM")
    Dim powershell As Management.Automation.PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()
    powershell.Commands = command
    Dim results = powershell.Invoke()
```

There are no items in the results, and the disk isn't cleared.

If I am executing the same command via Powershell, I get a prompt if I really wish to clear the disk, and everything is working.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Check `powershell.HadErrors` and `powershell.Streams.Error`

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the `Clear-Disk` confirmation prompt via `-confirm`:

```
command.AddScript("clear-disk -number 1 -removedata -removeOEM -confirm:$false")
```